# Numpy and tensorflow RNN shape representation mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I'm building my first RNN in tensorflow. After understanding all the concepts regarding the 3D input shape, I came across with this issue.

In my numpy version (1.15.4), the shape representation of 3D arrays is the following: `(panel, row, column)`. I will make each dimension different so that it is clearer:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                  

In [2]: arr = np.arange(30).reshape((2,3,5))                                                                                                

In [3]: arr                                                                                                                                 
Out[3]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])

In [4]: arr.shape                                                                                                                           
Out[4]: (2, 3, 5)

In [5]: np.__version__                                                                                                                      
Out[5]: '1.15.4'
```

Here my understanding is: **I have two timesteps with each timestep having 3 observations with 5 features in each observation.**

However, in tensorflow "theory" (which I believe it is strongly based in numpy) RNN cells expect tensors (i.e. just n-dimensional matrices) of shape `[batch_size, timesteps, features]`, which could be translated to: `(row, panel, column)` in the numpy "jargon".

As can be seen, the representation doesn't match, leading to errors when feeding numpy data into a placeholder, which in most of the examples and theory is defined like:

`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_TIMESTEPS_X, N_FEATURES], name='XPlaceholder')`

- `np.reshape()` doesn't solve the issue because it just rearranges the dimensions, but messes up with the data.
- I'm using for the first time the **Dataset API**, but I encounter the problems once into the session, not in the Dataset API ops.
- I'm using the `static_rnn` method, and everything works well until I have to feed the data into the placeholder, which obviously results in a shape error.
- I have tried to change the placeholder shape to `shape=[N_TIMESTEPS_X, None, N_FEATURES]`. HOWEVER, I'm using the dataset API, and I get errors when making the initializer if I change the Xplaceholder to the `shape=[N_TIMESTEPS_X, None, N_FEATURES]`.

So, to summarize:

- **First problem:** Shape errors with different shape representations.
- **Second problem:** Dataset error when equating the shape representations (I think that either static_rnn or dynamic_rnn would function if this is resolved).

**My question is:**

¿Is there anything I'm missing in regard to this different representation logic which makes the practice confusing?

¿Could the solution be attained to switching to dynamic_rnn? (although the problems about the shape I encounter are related to the dataset API initializer being fed with shape [N_TIMESTEPS_X, None, N_FEATURES], not with the RNN cell itself.

Thank you very much for your time.

**Full code:**

```
'''The idea is to create xt, yt, xval and yval. My numpy arrays to 
be fed are of the following shapes: 

The 3D xt array has a shape of: (11, 69579, 74)
The 3D xval array has a shape of: (11, 7732, 74)

The yt array has a shape of: (69579, 3)
The yval array has a shape of: (7732, 3)

'''

N_TIMESTEPS_X = xt.shape[0] ## The stack number
BATCH_SIZE = 256
#N_OBSERVATIONS = xt.shape[1]
N_FEATURES = xt.shape[2]
N_OUTPUTS = yt.shape[1]
N_NEURONS_LSTM = 128 ## Number of units in the LSTMCell 
N_NEURONS_DENSE = 64 ## Number of units in the Dense layer
N_EPOCHS = 600
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

### Define the placeholders anda gather the data.
train_data = (xt, yt)
validation_data = (xval, yval)

## We define the placeholders as a trick so that we do not break into memory problems, associated with feeding the data directly.
'''As an alternative, you can define the Dataset in terms of tf.placeholder() tensors, and feed the NumPy arrays when you initialize an Iterator over the dataset.'''
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_TIMESTEPS_X, N_FEATURES], name='XPlaceholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_OUTPUTS], name='YPlaceholder')

# Creating the two different dataset objects.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

# Creating the Iterator type that permits to switch between datasets.
itr = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
train_init_op = itr.make_initializer(train_dataset)
validation_init_op = itr.make_initializer(val_dataset)

next_features, next_labels = itr.get_next()

### Create the graph 
cellType = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=N_NEURONS_LSTM, name='LSTMCell')
inputs = tf.unstack(next_features, N_TIMESTEPS_X, axis=0)
'''inputs: A length T list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size]'''
RNNOutputs, _ = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell=cellType, inputs=inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
predictionsLayer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=tf.layers.batch_normalization(RNNOutputs[-1]), units=N_NEURONS_DENSE, activation=None, name='Dense_Layer')

### Define the cost function, that will be optimized by the optimizer. 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=predictionsLayer, labels=next_labels, name='Softmax_plus_Cross_Entropy'))
optimizer_type = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='AdamOptimizer')
optimizer = optimizer_type.minimize(cost)

### Model evaluation 
correctPrediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictionsLayer,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPrediction,tf.float32))
#confusionMatrix = tf.confusion_matrix(next_labels, predictionsLayer, num_classes=3, name='ConfMatrix')
N_BATCHES = train_data[0].shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE

## Saving variables so that we can restore them afterwards.
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_dir = '/home/zmlaptop/Desktop/tfModels/{}_{}'.format(cellType.__class__.__name__, datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
os.mkdir(save_dir)
varDict = {'nTimeSteps':N_TIMESTEPS_X, 'BatchSize': BATCH_SIZE, 'nFeatures':N_FEATURES,
           'nNeuronsLSTM':N_NEURONS_LSTM, 'nNeuronsDense':N_NEURONS_DENSE, 'nEpochs':N_EPOCHS,
           'learningRate':LEARNING_RATE, 'optimizerType': optimizer_type.__class__.__name__}
varDicSavingTxt = save_dir + '/varDict.txt'
modelFilesDir = save_dir + '/modelFiles'
os.mkdir(modelFilesDir)

logDir = save_dir + '/TBoardLogs'
os.mkdir(logDir)

acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Accuracy', accuracy)
loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Cost_CrossEntropy', cost)
summary_merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

with open(varDicSavingTxt, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(repr(varDict))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.set_random_seed(2)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logDir + '/train', sess.graph)
    validation_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logDir + '/validation')

    # initialise iterator with train data
    sess.run(train_init_op, feed_dict = {x : train_data[0], y: train_data[1], batch_size: BATCH_SIZE})

    print('¡Training starts!')
    for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):

        batchAccList = []
        tot_loss = 0

        for batch in range(N_BATCHES):

            optimizer_output, loss_value, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, summary_merged])
            accBatch = sess.run(accuracy)
            tot_loss += loss_value
            batchAccList.append(accBatch)

            if batch % 10 == 0:

                train_writer.add_summary(summary, batch)

        epochAcc = tf.reduce_mean(batchAccList)

        if epoch%10 == 0:

            print("Epoch: {}, Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}".format(epoch, tot_loss / N_BATCHES, epochAcc))

    #confM = sess.run(confusionMatrix)
    #confDic = {'confMatrix': confM}
    #confTxt = save_dir + '/confMDict.txt'
    #with open(confTxt, 'w') as outfile:
    #    outfile.write(repr(confDic))
    #print(confM)

    # initialise iterator with validation data
    sess.run(validation_init_op, feed_dict = {x : validation_data[0], y: validation_data[1], batch_size:len(validation_data[0])})
    print('Validation Loss: {:4f}, Validation Accuracy: {}'.format(sess.run(cost), sess.run(accuracy)))
    summary_val = sess.run(summary_merged)
    validation_writer.add_summary(summary_val)

    saver.save(sess, modelFilesDir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything I'm missing in regard to this different
>   representation logic which makes the practice confusing?

In fact, you made a mistake about the input shapes of `static_rnn` and `dynamic_rnn`. The input shape of `static_rnn` is `[timesteps,batch_size, features]`([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn)),which is a list of 2D tensors of shape [batch_size, features]. But The input shape of `dynamic_rnn` is either `[timesteps,batch_size, features]` or `[batch_size,timesteps, features]` depending on `time_major` is True or False([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn)).

> Could the solution be attained to switching to dynamic_rnn?

The key is not that you use `static_rnn` or `dynamic_rnn`, but that your data shape matches the required shape. The general format of placeholder is like your code is `[None, N_TIMESTEPS_X, N_FEATURES]`. It's also convenient for you to use dataset API.
You can use `transpose()`([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)) instead of `reshape()`.`transpose()` will permute the dimensions of an array and won't messes up with the data.

So your code needs to be modified.

```
# permute the dimensions
xt = xt.transpose([1,0,2])
xval = xval.transpose([1,0,2])

# adjust shape,axis=1 represents timesteps
inputs = tf.unstack(next_features,  axis=1)
```

Other errors should have nothing to do with rnn shape.

Comment: Many many thanks for the answer and time @giser_yugang. The `tf.transpose()` was the method I was missing, together with changing the axis in unstack. However, I think that in your answer there is a typo regarding `static_rnn` input shape; it is not really a 3D input, it is a list of 2D tensors of shape [batch_size, features]. The lenght of the list is the number of timesteps. ¿Could you please edit that so that others don't get confused? I totally understand your view, but I think it is much clearer this way, as in the docs. Again, many thanks and correct answer!

Comment: Regarding my above code, runs until the `optimizer_output, loss_value, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, summary_merged])`. There I encounter an error with the Yplaceholder: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'YPlaceholder' with dtype float and shape [?,3]
         [[node YPlaceholder (defined at /home/zmlaptop/Desktop/scripts_final/X8AImodelApp3Mod.py:34)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]] -- I understand the error but the `yt` I'm feeding is (69579, 3). Any idea?

Comment: @Ezarate11 As the error shows, you have to feed a value in your `sess.run([optimizer, cost, summary_merged])`.  `sess.run()` must feed a value every time in Tensorflow. In fact, we rarely feed all data into the model, usually feed batch data.

Comment: many thanks again. You are right; feeding a value eliminates the error. I don’t quite get about when to feed a value to sess.run, as I see examples with no feed_dict in the call. What is the rule? For example, do I need to feed a value also in the case of others like sess.run(accuracy), sess.run(epochAcc), sess.run(cost) and sess.run(summary_merged)? Appreacite your time.

Comment: @Ezarate11 This is because tensorflow is a static graph.You can actually get multiple outputs by feeding data at a time. For example `accuracy,cost=sess.run([accuracy,cost],feed_dict =...)`. Stackoverflow don't recommend discussion in comment. If you have any questions, you can ask new questions. Of course, similar problems are easy to find in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Alright @giser_yugang. Thank you very much for all the help. I will post another question if I don't get the info in my search.