# How does the input to a LSTM should look like?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Imagine, you are training a LSTM model in tensorflow for a sequence classification task. At each time step you have a binary vector `v_i` (For example, `v_i=[0, 1, 0, 1]`) and for each sequence you have variable number of time steps (the lengths of the binary vectors `v_i` are equal though).

When training your LSTM model in tensorflow as follows:

```py
lstm_cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(number_of_hidden) 
tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn (lstm_cell, training_data)
```

Does a single training sequence (with three time steps, `v_1=[0, 1, 0, 1]`, `v_2=[1, 1, 1, 0]` and `v_3=[0, 0, 1, 1]`) should look like

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

or

```
[[0], [1], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1]]
```

or something else?

I'm a little confused about how LSTMCell processes the inputs at each time step.

Comment: The input shape of `static_rnn` is `[timesteps,batch_size, features]`. which is a list of 2D tensors of shape `[batch_size, features]`. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53947413/7389608. So it should `[[[0, 1, 0, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 0]], [[0, 0, 1, 1]]]`.

Comment: Thanks, @giser_yugang!

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

The input shape of `static_rnn` is `[timesteps,batch_size, features]`. which is a list of 2D tensors of shape `[batch_size, features]`. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946149/numpy-and-tensorflow-rnn-shape-representation-mismatch/53947413#53947413). So it should `[[[0, 1, 0, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 0]], [[0, 0, 1, 1]]]`